# pdf created using itext jar giving error(not supported or damaged) at opening ,I am using itext version 5.3.0

Tags: java, pdf-generation

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/newfile2.pdf"));
document.open();
Anchor anchorTarget = new Anchor("First page of the document.");

anchorTarget.setName("BackToTop");
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();

paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(50);

paragraph1.add(anchorTarget);
document.add(paragraph1);

document.add(new Paragraph("Some more text on the \first page with different color and font type.", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD, new CMYKColor(0, 255, 0, 0))));
```

I have tried this, PDF is created but at opening it is showing error also size of file is 0 bytes.

Comment: I don't see you closing `document`. If you indeed don't close it, this would be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PdfWriter` coupled with a `Document` stores the page content when the page is finished. A page is finished as soon as either the next page is started or the `Document is closed.

In case of as little content as in the OP's sample on only a single page and without a `close` call, therefore, it is not surprising that the OP observed that the *size of file is 0 byte.*

Furthermore each PDF file ends with a special document part containing some document meta data and a cross reference table of the objects in the file. This part also is written when closing the `Document`.

To make his program produce a valid PDF with the intended contents, therefore, the OP has to eventually close the document:

```
document.close();
```